# How do I plot a function with a summation in ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

Let's say I have a vector `x = 1:5`. Suppose I wanted to plot the formula

[image]

where [image] in this example. **Note that `k` takes on all values in [0, 5], rather than just integers.**

How would I go about doing this in `ggplot2`?

Here is my attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
f <- function(k, vector){
sum((vector-k)^2/5)
}
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=c(0, 5)), aes(x)) +
stat_function(fun=f, geom='line', args(list(vector=y)))

Error in (function (k, vector)  : 
  argument "vector" is missing, with no default
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

I apologize if I seem ignorant; I am new to `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. First, your function needs to be properly vectorized for the variable you want to plot. `sum` will collapse the result. The easiest way to fix is with

```
f <- Vectorize(function(k, vector){
    sum((vector-k)^2/5)
}, "k")
```

Secondly, `args=` is a parameter, not a function when callingg `stat_function`. Use

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=c(0, 5)), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun=f, geom='line', args=list(vector=y))
```

This will give you

[image]