# Plotting a Function with Indicator terms

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664971/how-do-i-plot-a-function-with-a-summation-in-ggplot2), suppose I have a vector `x<-1:10` and I wanted to plot the formula
[image]

where I is an indicator function (e.g., I(x_i <= 5) = 1 when x_i <= 5, 0 otherwise), and x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_10) = (1, 2, ..., 10) using `ggplot2`.

How would I even start this? The problem with this formula is that I don't know how to handle conditional functions in `R` whose values are dependent on the *individual* values of a vector, and then taking a product of these complicates the problem even more. I imagine there's some sort of `Vectorize` that is necessary to produce the product, but I'm at a loss as to how to start.

Comment: Do I understand your function correctly that you want 1/t * 2/t * 3/t * 4/t * 5/t * 6^2 * 7^2 * 8^2 * 9^2 * 10^2?

Comment: @Heroka Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Heroka I mean, I could type it out, but I would like to generalize this for any `x`.

Comment: I was just checking, my function notation-reading skills are rusty.

Comment: There is a `prod` function in base R that will multiply all elements of a vector.

Comment: @akrun I apologize; I wasn't sure how to handle it after being duplicated. I can put it back up.

Comment: It's okay.  I didn't find that it got dupe tag.  Then, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every case is different, but in your case it is very easy to handle individuals values of `x` using the following function:

```
f <- function(t, x) prod((x <= 5) * x / t + (x > 5) * x^2)
```

It is based on vectorization, e.g. comparison `x <= 5` is done element-wise and returns a logical vector.

```
library(ggplot2)
ts <- seq(1, 2, length = 1000)
data <- data.frame(t = ts, y = sapply(ts, f, x = 1:10))
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = t, y = y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Using `stat_function` we redefine `f` to take only one argument (`t`), specify `x` separately, give a range of values of `t`, and use `Vectorize` to vectorize `f` w.r.t. `t`:

```
x <- 1:10
f <- function(t) prod((x <= 5) * x / t + (x > 5) * x^2)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(t = c(1, 2)), aes(t)) +
  stat_function(fun = Vectorize(f), geom = "line")
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Thank you. Could you maybe show how this can be done using `stat_function`?

Answer (score 0):

Indicator functions are very simple to construct using the `?Comparison` operators. The functions involved inside that product are all vectorized so this is perhaps what you are looking for:

```
> fI5 <- function(x, t=1.5) prod( (x <= 5)*x/t + (x>5)*x^2 )
> fI5(1:10)
[1] 14450688000
```